# Javascript Loop only return the last value when using .empty function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I want to append the data only into a specific ID `myID`. It only prints the last value of the loop which is `3`.

```
 setInterval(sample, 2000);
 function sample()
 {
   for(var i=0;i<=3;i++)
     {
         $('.found .find').each(function() {
             if(this.id == "myID")
              {
                // if the ID of this element is equal to #myID
                // this is the place where the data will append
                $(this).empty();
                $(this).append(i);
              }
         });
     }

 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="found">
      <div class="find" id="myID"></div>
</div>

 <div class="found">
      <div class="find" id="anID"></div>
</div>

<div class="found">
      <div class="find" id="anID2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"It works for me but it ONly prints THe last value of the loop which is 3"_ Try _not_ calling `.empty()` , which would remove previously appended `i`

Comment: @guest271314 If i get rid of `.empty()` it will not stop in appending data. Infinity

Comment: Is requirement to append 0, wait two seconds, append 1, up to 3, then start again ? Or, append 0123, 0123 infinitely ?

Comment: @guest271314 No it is not. Just append 0123

Comment: Just append 0123 continuously ? See post.

Comment: @guest271314 No. One time only. Not infinit append

Comment: Why is `setInterval` or `for` loop used if appending _"One time only"_ ? What is expected result ?

Comment: `0123` only. I used setINterval because it will update every 2sec

Comment: Yes. See updated post. `0123` is updated at `.find` `html` every two seconds.

Comment: This is a very backward way to achieve what you are looking for. After reading the comments, I'm unsure as to why you are asking for "numbers instead of strings", why you cant just append the value "0123" to your div directly `$('#myDiv').val("0123");`, why you are confused about the fact that `.empty()` is causing only the last value `3` to appear, why you need to loop through all of the `.found .find` divs when theres a unique id.. maybe some clarification is in order?

Comment: because it is an array. An array from php. A data from database.

Comment: _"because it is an array. An array from php."_ Why not mentioned at actual text of Question ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

`empty` removes all children from the given element, so you probably want to use it before the loop:

```
$('.found').empty();
for (var i=0; i <= 3; i++) {
  $('.found').append(i);
}
```

This will empty out the container, then append your list of elements (or numbers).

This can be used in an MVC framework's `render` method to empty the container of the previous render before adding new content.

Comment: Thank you man. But what if I have many `.found` class and Inside of each class has another `div` element with different ID? And I want the data to append only in the specific ID? PLease help me.

Comment: @KeanAllen I'm not quite sure what you mean. What DOM structure do you want to end up with? Some before and after examples would be super helpful.

Comment: @ssube PLease see improve question above. Thanks. Ill wait for reply

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$(function() {    
        setInterval(loop, 1000);
        function loop() {
          var n = "0123";
          for(var i=0;i<=3;i++) {
            $(".found").find(".find[id*=ID]").html(n);
          }    
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="found">
      <div class="find" id="myID"></div>
</div>

 <div class="found">
      <div class="find" id="anID"></div>
</div>

<div class="found">
      <div class="find" id="anID2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: aS I said. removing `.empty();` function will make the code append infinitely. Which is not what I want.

Comment: can u please change the .html(n) ti i? so that it prints the numbers? please. I will try to run it

Comment: @KeanAllen Tried stacksnippets ? "0123" is appended to `.find` . No "numbers" are printed ; "0123" is `String` within `html`

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code as You want it to happen just once
Run the original code if you want to keep doing it

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <style>

      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="found">
      Hello World
    </div>
    <div class="found">
          <div class="find" id="myID"></div>
    </div>

     <div class="found">
          <div class="find" id="anID">Append here</div>
    </div>

    <div class="found">
          <div class="find" id="anID2"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


    //$('#anID').empty();
for(var i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
    $('<p>'+i+'</p>').appendTo('#anID');

    //$('.found').append(i);
    //$('.found').append("\n"); 

}


});
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: see Improved question above

Comment: @KeanAllen changed as per your  requirement

Comment: what changed as per requirement?

Comment: Nothing changed, you can create as many div tags. Jquery will find appropriate  div based on id and start append 0123  to it

Comment: Thanks. I already had an answer I just improved your code. Thanks BTW. SEE my answer above

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function() {    
    setInterval(loop, 1000);
    function loop() {

        $(".found").find(".find[id*=ID]").empty();
      for(var i=0;i<=3;i++)
      {
        $(".found").find(".find[id*=ID]").prepend(i);
      }    
    }
});
```

Comment: Calling `.empty()` is not necessary. `.html()` will replace `html` within `.find(".find[id*=ID]")` . See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30222010/ . Also , at OP, requirement appeared to be "0123" , not "3210" ?

Comment: If `.html` it Only prints the last value, while `.empty()` it all prints the value :)

Comment: Also , at OP, requirement appeared to be "0123" , not "3210" _"0123 only"_  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221839/javascript-loop-only-return-the-last-value-when-using-empty-function/30222010?noredirect=1#comment48548872_30221839 ?